# Convert java rsa sign to php code using phpseclib

Tags: java, rsa, phpseclib

Can anyone help me to convert from java sign to php code using phpseclib

```java
public string SignData(string _data,string _priKey)
 {
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
 rsa.FromXmlString(_priKey);
 UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
 byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes(_data);
 byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(dataToEncrypt,'sha256');
 string result = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
 return result;
 }
```

I'm using this but it doesn't work (in laravel)

```php
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->setHash('sha256');
$rsa->setSignatureMode(2);
$privateXmlKey = '<RSAKeyValue><Modulus></Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P></P><Q></Q><DP></DP><DQ></DQ><InverseQ></InverseQ><D></D></RSAKeyValue>';
$rsa->loadKey($privateXmlKey, 2);
$text = 'sample data';
$plainText = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-16');
$sign = $rsa->sign($plainText);
$sign = base64_encode($sign);
```

I've tried both signature mode: `CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1` and `CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PSS`

Thank so much

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What is the result you get? What is the result you should get? Also, your `$privateXmlKey` looks wrong, there are a lot of information missing in that XML data. Which version of "phpseclib\Crypt\RSA" are you using? And don't use magic constants like `2`, but instead use the defined constants like `CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_XML` and `CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1`. How do you check the signature?

Comment: xml key is private so I cannot show it here, I've cleaned it. The results are different between 2 functions after signing, I mean the `$sign` from php function and `result` from java with same `privatexmlkey` and input string.
`CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_XML` and `CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1` are defined from phpseclib.

Comment: @ytdm - it'd none-the-less make for much more readable code if you used the constants instead of the numbers they resolve to.

Comment: @ytdm - your Java code looks more like C#. Anyway, I'd say (1) retag your question if my C# assumption is indeed correct and (2) generate a private key that you are willing to share that reproduces the problem. Post it and the signature that you get with both the C# / Java code and the PHP code. One thing to keep in mind with `CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PSS` is that the signature will be different every time as randomized padding is utilized.

Comment: Thanks @neubert, you reminded me about the signature will be different every time. So the verify code would works. I cannot run java code now to make sure both work the same.